# jfxtras, how to populate a listView with the selected items in a CalendarPicker?

Tags: java, listview, datepicker, javafx, jfxtras

would like to know ¿how to populate a listView with the selected items  in a CalendarPicker (mode Multiple)??
This functionality is shown in app "JFXTras 8.0 Samples" http://jfxtras.org/resources/java/jfxtras-labs-samples-8.0-r2-SNAPSHOT-shadow.jar
Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to ask such question would where the project says user can post their questions. I've completely missed this one, and since I wrote CalendarPicker and the sample that is a shame.

CalendarPicker has a calenders property, which is an observable list of the selected calendars. This can be handed over to ListView's setItems. Changes are automatically updated due to JavaFX's binding.